# How much time until the state data is PoW validated when using parity warp?

Tags: synchronization, parity, proof-of-work, state-trie, warp-sync

Ethcore claims `parity --warp`  only takes one minute to [sync the chain](https://twitter.com/ethcoreproject/status/803881754515927040). I tried myself and it indeed takes around 2-3 minutes on my machine with a slightly bad connection.

```
 0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ parity --mode passive --db-compaction ssd --pruning fast --warp --cache-size 4096
2016-11-30 12:21:26  Starting Parity/v1.4.5-beta-UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.13.0
2016-11-30 12:21:26  State DB configuation: fast
2016-11-30 12:21:26  Operating mode: passive
2016-11-30 12:21:26  Configured for Frontier/Homestead using Ethash engine
2016-11-30 12:21:32  Syncing snapshot 1/69         #0    4/10/25 peers      3 MiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync
                     [...]
2016-11-30 12:23:43  Syncing snapshot 68/69         #0    1/14/25 peers      3 MiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync
2016-11-30 12:23:48  Syncing #2720000 e0a7…f90a      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s       0+    0 Qed   #2720000    8/11/25 peers    0 bytes db  656 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   12 KiB sync
2016-11-30 12:23:56  Syncing #2720149 3f85…a2c7    120 blk/s  979 tx/s  40 Mgas/s       0+  613 Qed   #2721511    8/14/25 peers     23 MiB db    2 MiB chain    5 MiB queue    1 MiB sync
2016-11-30 12:23:57  Imported #2721511 3702…acd3 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 1.02 ms, 0.51 KiB) + another 3 block(s) containing 4 tx(s)
2016-11-30 12:24:11  Imported #2721512 e6c5…2d67 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 0.74 ms, 0.51 KiB)
```

But, how [much time does it take](https://twitter.com/peter_szilagyi/status/803900717907976192) until the state data is PoW validated? And, is it validated at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--warp` downloads the most recent 30k blocks and quickly validates for PoW and total difficulty. This is what's taking around 1-5 minutes.

```
 0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ parity --mode active --db-compaction ssd --warp --cache-size 4096
2016-12-01 22:27:08  Starting Parity/v1.4.5-beta-UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.13.0
2016-12-01 22:27:08  State DB configuation: fast
2016-12-01 22:27:08  Operating mode: active
2016-12-01 22:27:08  Configured for Frontier/Homestead using Ethash engine
2016-12-01 22:27:14  Public node URL: enode://94ea88a67d176eac49e5aa64aa277aa5bd48e96bb549c1852545d943dedc4409039072766387597b415a9ccd38167ab848bfdf93919009d2d942687aa8ccb714@172.16.16.11:30303
2016-12-01 22:27:19  Syncing snapshot 0/66         #0    3/11/25 peers      3 MiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync
-------------------- ^ warp started ------------------------------------------------

                     [...]

2016-12-01 22:30:14  Syncing snapshot 61/66         #0    3/16/25 peers      3 MiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync
2016-12-01 22:30:19  Syncing #2730000 fa0e…0b90      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s       0+    0 Qed   #2730000    2/16/25 peers    0 bytes db    8 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync
-------------------- ^ warp finished -----------------------------------------------

2016-12-01 22:30:21  Imported #2730131 adda…db11 (3 txs, 0.09 Mgas, 1.59 ms, 0.99 KiB)
2016-12-01 22:30:54       #59817   14/15/25 peers      3 MiB db   23 MiB chain  0 bytes queue    6 MiB sync
------------------------- ^ normal sync started ------------------------------------

2016-12-01 22:31:17  Imported #2730134 68eb…bd60 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 7.36 ms, 1.03 KiB) + another 1 block(s) containing 16 tx(s)
2016-12-01 22:31:29       #72301   11/13/25 peers      3 MiB db   26 MiB chain  0 bytes queue    6 MiB sync
2016-12-01 22:30:09  Syncing snapshot 57/66         #0    3/15/25 peers      3 MiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync

                     [...]

2016-12-02 00:45:36  Imported #2730701 ad59…c8b8 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 1.05 ms, 0.52 KiB) + another 2 block(s) containing 27 tx(s)
2016-12-02 00:45:48  Imported #2730702 2a08…4c17 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 0.68 ms, 0.51 KiB)
2016-12-02 00:45:53  Imported #2730701 fcb0…d533 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 6.60 ms, 0.51 KiB)
2016-12-02 00:45:55  Imported #2730704 a5c7…076d (19 txs, 0.47 Mgas, 12.23 ms, 3.41 KiB)
2016-12-02 00:46:04     #2677968   18/20/25 peers      5 MiB db  215 MiB chain  0 bytes queue   25 MiB sync
2016-12-02 00:46:39     #2691893   21/23/25 peers      5 MiB db  219 MiB chain  0 bytes queue   21 MiB sync
----------------------- ^ normal sync finished -------------------------------------

2016-12-02 00:47:14      0/24/25 peers      5 MiB db  223 MiB chain  0 bytes queue   68 KiB sync
2016-12-02 00:47:20  Imported #2730707 1bc4…6d75 (0 txs, 0.00 Mgas, 0.32 ms, 0.51 KiB) + another 1 block(s) containing 2 tx(s)
-------------------- ^ receiving new blocks ----------------------------------------
```

After that the full blockchain is synchronized and PoW validated. This took a little bit more than 2 hours with my setup in fast pruning mode, see timestamps above.